# Insert the mysqli_insert_id inside separate table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to submit new registered user with AUTO_INCREMENT id inside table1 and at the same time insert mysqli_insert_id or LAST_INSERT_ID what ever you want to call it inside table2. I can echo id out, but I need it inside my table2. How can I accomplish that? Please help!
Here is my code for reference:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

require 'connect.php';

$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (username, password) 
     VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."','".$_POST["password"]."')";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
   $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
     echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}
mysqli_close($con);
}

?>
```

Comment: id = last_insert_id() query insert etc.? pretty straightforward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the variable from the last inserted id from the (successful) query to INSERT into the other table.

This is a rough sketch as we don't know what the db schema is for your second table and is quite unclear, so you will need to do (fill in) the rest.

```
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
   $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
     echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;

     $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO table2 (col) VALUES ('$last_id')")
            or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

**Important sidenote about column length:**

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or the compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. Tested works perfect. Thank you for extra info I'll take it for consideration.

Comment: @SergeyM. Oh, great! Glad to hear that this worked out for you, *cheers and you're welcome*